# Problem with operations on exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Okay, this is a very basic doubt, and I would like to know where exactly the mistake is.

Let's take the equality $1^2=1$

Now I do it this way Step 1: $1^2 = 1^\frac{4}{2}$

Step2: $\implies (1^4)^\frac{1}{2}$

Step3: $\implies 1^\frac{1}{2} = \pm 1$

The answer should be only one but I am also getting minus one.
I know it obviously is a mistake, but I would like to know which exact step and in which particular operation the mistake is....

Answer (score 6):

Given a positive number $a$, $a^\frac12$ is defined to be the *positive* number $b$ such that $b^2=a$. In particular, $1^\frac12=1,$ even though $(-1)^2=1,$ too.

Comment: Okay but how about for a complex number? For example: $i^2 = i^\frac{4}{2} = (i^4)^\frac{1}{2} = 1^\frac{1}{2}$ which is equal to 1 if your definition is true for complex numbers.......

Comment: Ah! The definition I gave is for what is called the *principal branch* of the square root function. For a given non-zero complex number and a positive integer $n$, there are $n$ distinct ways that we can define $z^\frac1n$. (We usually like to define this function so it is continuous "almost everywhere," and so that it agrees with our usual real definition of $n$th root.) Unfortunately, the usual exponent rules needn't all apply in general if we're dealing with complex numbers, as your example shows.

Comment: One way to get around that is by declaring the $n$th roots to be "multi-valued functions." That has its upsides and downsides, though.

Comment: Alright but can I know which exponent rules apply and which don't? (while solving problems in variables things are not very obvious, and doing certain operations lead to wrong answers)

Comment: You can find more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_of_complex_numbers) and in particular [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities).

Answer (score 2):

Cameron's answer is probably the best one to give, but there's another aspect which I think is worth pointing out.

Look at the following argument:
$$x=0\implies x(x-1)=0\implies x=0,1$$

This is completely true! There's nothing actually wrong with the conclusion that "IF $x=0$ THEN $x=0,1$". You're just being less specific. What you can't do is reverse the logic.

Comment: exactly, but look at your second step, you multiplied both sides of the equation by (x-1). We can do this only if x-1 is not equal to zero, implying x not equal to one, and hence 1 is not a valid solution. Sk the mistake is precisely in the second step. Now I would like to know what the mistake in my calculation is.

Comment: No! You don't need $x-1\neq 0$ in order to *multiply* by it, only to *divide* by it. Hence the logic works from left to right as written,  just you can't reverse it. My point is that your conclusion in the question is valid when interpreted as $1=\pm 1$ meaning "**either** $1=+1$ or $1=-1$". In general, $x^2=a^2\implies x=\pm a$ is true even though we might have more information which rules out one possibility.

Comment: Just to make clear, $x=\pm 1$ does **not** usually mean "$x=-1$ and $x=1$ are **both** solutions to the current problem". It means "any solution must be either 1  or -1" which is very different.

Comment: However, as Cameron says, your specific statement does indeed have more information. Because we know $1^{1/2}$ is the correct expression for the number sought, one can conclude it must be $+1$ specifically. In general, one adopts a convention for writing $z=re^{i\theta}$ like $-\pi<\theta\le\pi$ and $r\ge 0$, then defines $z^{1/2}=\sqrt r e^{i\theta/2}$. This is an unambiguous definition of the *principal branch* of the square root.